# Dynamically load a Kotlin class based on a parameter value

Tags: kotlin

I'm teaching myself Kotlin. I need to load a class from my app dynamically based on a command line parameter that is passed in. In Java, I do this:

```
var cl = App.class.getClassLoader();
var euler = (Euler) cl
        .loadClass("com.gorauskas.euler.solutions.Euler" + Util.problem)
        .getDeclaredConstructor()
        .newInstance();
```

Where `Euler` is an interface that all classes in the `com.gorauskas.euler.solutions` package implement, and `Util.problem` is an int passed in on the command line ... ([code here](https://github.com/gorauskas/Euler.Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gorauskas/euler/App.java))

How can I load a class dynamically in Kotlin like the Java example above?

I have tried the following:

```
val cl = this.javaClass.classLoader
val e = cl.loadClass("com.gorauskas.euler.solutions.Euler" + problem)
    .getDeclaredConstructor()
    .newInstance()
```

And I can see the properties of the instance in IntelliJ, but I cannot access the properties by using `e.problem`, for instance, and instead I get a `Unresolved reference` error.

[image]

***Update (2019-09-09 03:20 UTC):***

If I use the `as` casting operator, then I can access the members of my instance ...

```
val e: EulerInterface = cl.loadClass(EULER_PACKAGE + EULER_CLASS + problem)
    .getDeclaredConstructor()
    .newInstance() as EulerInterface
```

But this feels like a hack to me ... Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: That looks idiomatic to me. You don't need the type in the `val` any more, but other than that, you're doing it as idiomatically as I can imagine.